# Maven Android instrumentation test output

Tags: android, maven, junit

As an experiment, I am trying to use maven to build the Google Android market licensing library, sample, and test projects. Here is the pom.xml for the test project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>etherwalker.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>license_test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>License - Instrumentation Tests</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>etherwalker.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>license_parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>etherwalker.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>license_sample</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apk</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>etherwalker.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>license_sample</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn install` in that project, I get the following error when the android instrumentation unit tests are run:

```
[INFO] C:\usr\android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/adb.exe [shell, am, instrument, -w, com.example.android.market.licensing.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner]


com.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscatorTest:.......

com.android.vending.licensing.ObfuscatedPreferencesTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException

INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.io.EOFException: EOF encountered in middle of object

INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

What I really want to know is, where can I find the junit results, and especially the stack trace for the exception?

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when nothing to test (your main project not build).

the structure of your maven project must be:

**your_project-parent**

**|--your_project**

**|--your_project-it**

When

**your_project** - main project

**your_project-parent** - parent project

**your_project-it** - instrumental testing project

You must run mvn install on **your_project-perent** project.

Then first builds main project then test project.